# Concat two variable names to get the name of a third variable

Tags: excel, vba, variables

I'm trying to get my code to loop through a selection of search words by applying the search words to a variable named FindText which increments by 1 each time it's looped through.

```
Dim FindText1 As String, FindText2 As String, ListText As String
Dim FindText As Variant

FindText1 = "Name"
FindText2 = "Surname"

For i = 1 To 2

    Dim Onecell As Range

    FindText = "FindText" & i

    For Each Onecell In Range("A1:AA1")
        If InStr(UCase(Onecell.Text), UCase(FindText)) > 0 Then
            ListText = ListText + vbNewLine + Onecell.Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False) + " | " + Onecell.Value
        End If
    Next Onecell

    MsgBox ListText, vbQuestion, FindText

Next i
```

Each time I run this the FindText variable within the InStr formula shows as Text and is "FindText1" one the first instance and "FindText2" on the second. But it doesn't actually return the variable FindText1 or FindText2.

I have also tried using the following:

```
If InStr(UCase(Onecell.Text), UCase("FindText" & i)) > 0 Then
```

But this also doesn't work.

Is it possible to achieve this?

Comment: In VBA to concatenate strings use "&" rather than "+".

Comment: Sorry, don't think `FindText = "FindText" & i` will work. Use an array instead.

Comment: `"FindText" & i` will resolve to the string (if `i=1`):  `FindText1`.  It will NOT return the contents of the variable `FindText1`.  As @SJR writes, Use an array to store your `FindText` words and loop through that.

Comment: Thanks @SJR & Ron Rosenfeld, I thought that might be the case I will have a read up arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an illustration, but you should read up on arrays as there is a lot to them, e.g. [here](https://excelmacromastery.com/excel-vba-array/).

```
Sub x()

Dim ListText As String
Dim FindText(1 To 2) As String
Dim Onecell As Range

FindText(1) = "Name"
FindText(2) = "Surname"

For i = LBound(FindText) To UBound(FindText)
    For Each Onecell In Range("A1:AA1")
        If InStr(UCase(Onecell.Text), UCase(FindText(i))) > 0 Then
            ListText = ListText & vbNewLine & Onecell.Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False) & " | " & Onecell.Value
        End If
    Next Onecell
    MsgBox ListText, vbQuestion, FindText(i)
Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick example of using arrays to make your looping simpler:

```
Sub SearchMe()
    Dim searchWords() As String
    searchWords = Split("Name,Surname,LastName,First Name,AnotherName")

    Dim searchRange As Range
    Set searchRange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:AA1")

    Dim listText As String
    Dim word As String
    For Each word In searchWords
        Dim cell As Range
        For Each cell In searchRange
            If InStr(UCase(cell.Text), UCase(word)) > 0 Then
                listText = listText & vbNewLine & _
                           cell.Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False) & _
                           " | " & cell.Value
            End If
        Next cell
        MsgBox listText, vbQuestion, word
    Next word
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a collection, instead of an array. It's very simple to work with collections and I often find the easier and faster to implement than an array.

```
Dim colFind As New Collection
dim i As integer
Dim ListText As String

' Add the words you wish to search for to the collection.
colFind.Add "Name"
colFind.Add "Surname"

For i = 1 To colFind.Count

    Dim Onecell As Range

    For Each Onecell In Range("A1:AA1")
        If InStr(UCase(Onecell.Text), UCase(colFind(i))) > 0 Then
            ListText = ListText & vbNewLine & Onecell.Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False) & " | " & Onecell.Value
        End If
    Next Onecell

    MsgBox ListText, vbQuestion, colFind(i)

Next i
```